# How to make background image appear only once in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two *cells*, I set background image for *cells* from an array of images using JavaScript.

I have images

`image1= 150*150` named `image1` only once

`image2=150*150`  named `image2` only once

**when I set images as background image of *cells*, Image get repeated in each cell,**

i.e. `Image1` appear 3 times in `cell[1]` likewise.

`How to remove this and make background image appear only once in an **FIT TO THE ENTIRE** *cell*.

```js
var images = [
  {label: '1',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'},
  {label: '2',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'}
];

function bgsetting() {
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

  boxtags[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[0].url + ')'; 
  boxtags[1].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[1].url + ')'; 

}

bgsetting();
```

```css
.cell {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  border: 2px solid #333;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #99ffff;
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-size:contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell"  ></div>
  <div class="cell"  ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @pfx  i want the image to fit the entire cell is there any way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the `background-repeat` property to `no-repeat`. This will ensure that the background-image is not repeated. The image will only be shown once.

To fit the image into each cell you can use `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center`.

```js
var images = [{label: '1',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'},
{label: '2',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'}];

function bgsetting() {
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

  boxtags[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[0].url + ')'; 
  boxtags[1].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[1].url + ')'; 
}

bgsetting();
```

```css
.cell {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  border: 2px solid #333;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #99ffff;
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-size:contain;
  
  /* style to set image properly*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; 
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,    i want the image to fit the entire cell  is there any way ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this css and you're done...

```
.cell {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```js
var images = [

{label: '1',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'},
{label: '2',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'}];

function bgsetting() 
{
boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

boxtags[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[0].url + ')'; 
boxtags[1].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[1].url + ')'; 

}

bgsetting();
```

```css
.cell {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  border: 2px solid #333;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #99ffff;
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="cell"  ></div>
<div class="cell"  ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want the image to fit the entire cell is there any way ?

Comment: works fine background-size: cover;
    background-position: center thanks for help